# I am Unable to get Instagram Business Account ID through Facebook Graph api

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to access the media of my Instagram business account through Facebook Graph API. I'm following this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/

I've set up everything as requested: I have an Instagram business account, a Facebook page connected to this account and a Facebook app.
I am using Graph API explorer, and allowing all permissions that requires for instagram. But

In step 5, when I try to get the Instagram Account ID with

GET /v3.0/{page id}?fields=instagram_business_account

The Instagram business account field is missing, I only get back the ID of the Facebook page, which I already have.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong here? Below is my permissions image. [image]

Answer (score 2):

You just need extra permission: `pages_read_engagement`

Answer (score 1):

[image]i found the solution. At start be sure your instagram account should business account or Creator account. 
And then link it with facebook from Facebook web.
Error only come when we use our personal account instead of Creator or Business.

This is my output now.